# Change default sorting order in woocommerce dashboard screen

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to change the default sorting order in woocommerce admin screen.

I am trying the following code to sort the product page by product name by default.

```
/* Sort posts in wp_list_table by column in ascending or descending order. */
function custom_post_order($query){
    /* 
        Set post types.
        _builtin => true returns WordPress default post types. 
        _builtin => false returns custom registered post types. 
    */
    $post_types = get_post_types(array('_builtin' => false), 'names');
    /* The current post type. */
    $post_type = $query->get('post_type');
    /* Check post types. */
    if(in_array($post_type, $post_types) && $post_type == 'product'){
        /* Post Column: e.g. title */
        if($query->get('orderby') == ''){
            $query->set('orderby', 'title');
        }
        /* Post Order: ASC / DESC */
        if($query->get('order') == ''){
            $query->set('order', 'ASC');
        }
    }
}
if(is_admin()){
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_order');
}
```

But it does not seems to be working. Can anyone please point where I am going wrong Or does woocommerce handles product columns differently.

Answer (score 2):

I would target `parse_query` instead. This seems to be working for me:

```
/* Sort products in wp_list_table by column in ascending or descending order. */
function sp_41964737_custom_product_order( $query ){

    global $typenow;

    if( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $typenow == 'product' ){

        /* Post Column: e.g. title */
        if($query->get('orderby') == ''){
            $query->set('orderby', 'title');
        }
        /* Post Order: ASC / DESC */
        if($query->get('order') == ''){
            $query->set('order', 'ASC');
        }

    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'sp_41964737_custom_product_order' );
```

Results in:

[image: screenshot of ordered products]

Comment: Please try disabling other plugins and switching to a default theme to make sure that you don't have anything conflicting. I actually like the result so much I'm going to keep it on my test environment.