# Change order of orders in Woocommerce based on how much time is left by the date the order should be ready

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to change order of orders in Woocommerce admin page. I have some custom column with date / time and based on this data I will change the order of orders. It is not stricly date / time filtering (from oldest to newest or vice versa).

The decisive factor is how much time is left by the date the order should be ready. In my case, it's one hour. At that point, the order should be at the top of the list, regardless of whether it was created, for example, a week ago.

Examples:

1) Default ordering (newest on top, oldest on bottom)

```
+--------------------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+-------+
| ACTUAL DATE: 28.5.2020 - 15:00 |            |         |                    |       |
+--------------------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+-------+
| ORDER                          | DATE       | STATUS  | DATE/TIME (custom) | PRICE |
| Frank                          | 28.05.2020 | PENDING | -                  | 100   |
| Lucy                           | 27.05.2020 | DONE    | -                  | 50    |
| Thomas                         | 27.05.2020 | DONE    | -                  | 80    |
| Jane                           | 26.05.2020 | PENDING | 28.5.2020 - 16:00  | 90    |
+--------------------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+-------+
```

2) One hour left to complete Jane's order

```
+--------------------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+-------+
| ACTUAL DATE: 28.5.2020 - 15:00 |            |         |                    |       |
+--------------------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+-------+
| ORDER                          | DATE       | STATUS  | DATE/TIME (custom) | PRICE |
| Jane                           | 26.05.2020 | PENDING | 28.5.2020 - 16:00  | 90    |
| Frank                          | 28.05.2020 | PENDING | -                  | 100   |
| Lucy                           | 27.05.2020 | DONE    | -                  | 50    |
| Thomas                         | 27.05.2020 | DONE    | -                  | 80    |
+--------------------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+-------+
```

3) Two hour left to complete Jane's order

```
+--------------------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+-------+
| ACTUAL DATE: 28.5.2020 - 14:00 |            |         |                    |       |
+--------------------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+-------+
| ORDER                          | DATE       | STATUS  | DATE/TIME (custom) | PRICE |
| Frank                          | 28.05.2020 | PENDING | -                  | 100   |
| Lucy                           | 27.05.2020 | DONE    | -                  | 50    |
| Thomas                         | 27.05.2020 | DONE    | -                  | 80    |
| Jane                           | 26.05.2020 | PENDING | 28.5.2020 - 16:00  | 90    |
+--------------------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+-------+
```

Could you please give me a hint how to start? What hooks in my child theme function.php should I use?

EDIT:
Example code for adding new column:

```
// Add column
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_delivery_time' );
function custom_delivery_time( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = ( is_array( $columns ) ) ? $columns : array();
    unset( $new_columns[ 'order_actions' ] );

    $new_columns['custom_datetime'] = 'Date / Time';
    $new_columns[ 'order_actions' ] = $columns[ 'order_actions' ];

    return $new_columns;
}

// Change order of columns, populate
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'custom_woo_admin_value', 2 );
function custom_woo_admin_value( $column ) {
    global $post, $the_order;

    if ( empty( $the_order ) || $the_order->get_id() != $post->ID ) {
        $the_order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
    }

    if ( $column == 'custom_datetime' ) {
        $custom_datetime = $the_order->get_custom_datetime();
        echo empty($custom_datetime) ? '' : $custom_datetime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some additional questions: Do you want to add a new filter? make the column sortable? 
or that you immediately see the new sorting condition when viewing the admin order list page? It can also be useful to add the code to your question that you have used so far to create the new custom column.

Comment: I plan to add sorting as well, but I've done it in the past, so I have a some idea of how to do it. I should immediately see the new sorting condition when viewing the admin order list page. I do not started writing code for new column because I wanted to have idea how to done this thing as a whole. But I added example code to my question to have something to start with.

Comment: Nothing? I just need help on how to change the order based on an if condition.

Comment: **1)** first and foremost, the code you use to add the column can be more efficient, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61444370/11987538) 
where you will see that the use of global variables is not necessary. **2)** 
The following answers (even if they are somewhat outdated) can certainly help you on your way [Change default sorting order in woocommerce dashboard screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41967661/11987538) & [In Wordpress, how do I set the default admin sort order for a custom post type to a custom column?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31520570/11987538)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still struggling with this problem. I have no problem sorting orders by custom date or time for example from oldest, but I can't understand how to change the order based on some IF condition. Most sources only refer to sorting in ascending or descending order, but what if I want absolutly random order? First order would by five, second order move to position hundred, etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved it this way. I created a custom "priority" column, which contains a numeric value that determines how high in the list the order should be. I then sort orders according to this custom column from the smallest (highest priorty) to the largest. Whenever a admin "orders list" page is updated, the appropriate priority is selected according to the time of delivery.  I'm only interested in not finished orders, so there is not much to process.

I would still like to hear if someone comes up with a better solution.